# How to delete rows which has 4 values from 5 missing in a row

Tags: r, na

I'm trying to delete rows which has from 4 to 5 missing values in one row. I've already tried a code which I found here, but no success yet.

the example of dataset (dt) is:

```
id a b  c  d  e
1 10 NA NA 9  8
2 NA 7  7  NA NA
3 10 NA NA NA NA
```

Desired output:

```
id a b  c  d  e
1 10 NA NA 9  8
2 NA 7  7  NA NA
```

I used this code `dt[!apply(dt, 1, function(i) all(1:5 %in% which(is.na(i)))),]` but no success.

Any suggestion is high appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I am not selecting the first column, i.e. `id` because in the post it was mentioned 4 from 5 missing.  The number of columns in `dt` is 6.  So, I guess the first column `id` is not used.  `dt[,-1]` selects all other columns except the `id`.

```
 dt[rowSums(is.na(dt[,-1]))!=4,]
 #  id  a  b  c  d  e
 #1  1 10 NA NA  9  8
 #2  2 NA  7  7 NA NA
```

If you are using `apply`, you could use

```
dt[apply(dt[,-1], 1, function(i) sum(is.na(i))!=4),]
```

Suppose, you wanted to delete rows with `>=4` NAs, (from @Taras B's comments)

```
 dt[rowSums(is.na(dt[,-1])) <4,]
```

#### data

```
dt <- structure(list(id = 1:3, a = c(10L, NA, 10L), b = c(NA, 7L, NA
), c = c(NA, 7L, NA), d = c(9L, NA, NA), e = c(8L, NA, NA)), .Names = c("id", 
"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: This solves the problem I think.
@akrun - not sure why you exclude 1st column (id) though with `dt[,-1]`, it was not mentioned about that in the question. Also consider improving it to also cover 5 missing values too. It was asked "4 from 5 missing".

Comment: @Taras B Here the `ncol(dt)` is 6.  So, when the OP mentioned 4 of 5, I thought that the first column `id` is not included in the condition.  If the OP wanted 4 or more than 4 to be excluded, then `!=4` could be replaced by `<4`

Comment: I agree when following your thinking path, maybe it is not best formulation of the question then.

Comment: @Taras B Thanks for your comments. I updated the post.  Perhaps, the OP would give some explanation.

Comment: we can make like this:  `dt[rowSums(is.na(dt[2:6])) <4,] `